# PHP convert javascript when echo

Tags: php, javascript

I have following PHP echo statement:

`echo "<td><a href='delete-news.php?deleteID=".$id." onclick='return confirm('Really delete?');'>Delete</a></td>";`

which is convert to html as:

`<td class="last-td nth-8"><a delete?');'="" confirm('really="" return="" href="delete-news.php?deleteID=5 onclick=">Delete</a></td>`

As you can see something has gone wrong?
What is the problem? I have already tried swaping `" "` for single `' '`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot `'` after href. Use it like

**Double quotes:**

```
echo "<td><a href='delete-news.php?deleteID=".$id."' onclick=\"return confirm('Really delete?');\">Delete</a></td>";
```

**Single quotes:**

```
echo '<td><a href="delete-news.php?deleteID='.$id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Really delete?\');">Delete</a></td>';
```

Comment: Your example has the same error: http://awesomescreenshot.com/02aj6f761   There is no alert question on click, which is the goal.

Comment: Why extra marking? Is not simpler to use single ` ' ` on echo and than normal html inside the echo?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but why this is not correct: `'<td><a href="delete-news.php?deleteID='.$id.'" onclick="return confirm("Really delete?");">Delete</a></td>';`

Comment: you'Re closing onclick with " in confirm ()

Comment: This is only the case within PHP echo - not HTML / JS ?

Comment: no. it's case of both. look. this one " before `broken` is breaking `onclick` ... `<div onclick="confirm("broken here")"></div>`

Comment: @NewUser let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2847/discussion-between-genesis--and-newuser)

Answer (score 2):

Your have double single quotes in the `onclick` statement, try `confirm(\'Really delete?\')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have `href` not closed. Also, your `'Really delete'` cause trouble too. Try this

```
echo "<td><a href='delete-news.php?deleteID=$id' onclick='return confirm(\"Really delete?\");'>Delete</a></td>";
```